# administrative_area_level_2 missing when searching with latitude and longitude

Tags: google-places-api, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

Why is it that I do not get the **administrative_area_level_2** returned when **reverse geocoding** with **latitude and longitude** (India latitude and longitude)

1. 19.1165896, 72.8471527
2. 18.5204, 73.8567
3. 19.5761, 74.2070

Till yesterday it was returning administrative_area_level_2 value.

Answer (score 0):

This was a [Change to Address Component Types in India](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/258777366) that happened on the Google Maps APIs (including the Geocoding API) around November 14, 2022.

The results and address components that previously were `administrative_area_level_2` ([**districts**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_divisions_of_India#Districts) in India) became `administrative_area_level_3`.

Weeks later, **new** results and address components, representing [**divisions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_divisions_in_India#List_of_divisions) in India, were added as the new `administrative_area_level_2`.

If you haven't already, you may want to update your code to check for `administrative_area_level_3` now, instead of `administrative_area_level_2`.